# Unzip one file with libzip

Tags: c, eclipse, extract

I need to create an application to extract one file from zip archive, after which I want to compile it for Android.

I'm using Ubuntu, with libzip-0.10.1 pre-installed. 
I created C project in Eclipse, added include path and found simple script for extracting file. Unfortunately I cannot get the following to build and I could use some advice.

```
// zip.c file
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <zip.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
struct zip *zip_file;
struct zip_file *file_in_zip;
int err;
int files_total;
int file_number;
int r;
char buffer[10000];

if (argc < 3) {
    fprintf(stderr,"usage: %s <zipfile> <fileindex>\n",argv[0]);
    return -1;
};

zip_file = zip_open(argv[1], 0, &err);
if (!zip_file) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: can't open file %s\n",argv[1]);
    return -1;
};

file_number = atoi(argv[2]);
files_total = zip_get_num_files(zip_file);
if (file_number > files_total) {
    printf("Error: we have only %d files in ZIP\n",files_total);
    return -1;
};

file_in_zip = zip_fopen_index(zip_file, file_number, 0);
if (file_in_zip) {
    while ( (r = zip_fread(file_in_zip, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) {
        printf("%s",buffer);
    };
    zip_fclose(file_in_zip);
} else {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: can't open file %d in zip\n",file_number);
};

zip_close(zip_file);

return 0;
};
```

Also I added few .h files to include directory in my project and few .c files to directory with zip.c file. After that all dependences was good, but I have an error:

```
‘struct zip’ has no member named ‘default_password’ in file zip_fopen_index.c
```

The file `zip_fopen_index.c` is:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "zipint.h"


ZIP_EXTERN struct zip_file *
zip_fopen_index(struct zip *za, zip_uint64_t fileno, int flags)
{
    return zip_fopen_index_encrypted(za, fileno, flags, za->default_password); // error here
}
```

Comment: Were does the file `zip_fopen_index.c` come from? Did you wrote it?

Comment: in zip.c file present a function `zip_fopen_index` and Eclipse did not recognize it before I added `zip_fopen_index.c` file to the directory with `zip.c` file. And this file I found on the libzip source

Comment: try checking you `zipint.h` file, and scroll down to the definition for `struct * zip` to see if a `default_password` field is present.

Comment: Did problems in finding/recognizing only exist for `zip_fopen_index`, or also for the other `zip_*`functions? I bet the latter was the case wasn't it? @lubart

Comment: `struct zip` is a strcuture internal to `libzip`, though it's member's are not ment to be accessable from out side the library. @NickolayRatchev

Comment: I would note that version 0.10.1 is quite old nowadays (2017), though Debian and some other distributions may still be packaging 0.1x versions the library has passed the version 1.0 mark.  Significantly some of the library functions from the 0.1x era have been depreciated or declared obsolete (particularly error handling ones) and sample code snippets using the newer replacements will not build as the compiler or linker will not be able to find those new functions in old versions of the libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all allow me some comments:

Your program is **not compiled and linked** by Eclipse.

Compiling is done by the compiler (`gcc` using option `-c`):

```
make all 
Building file: ../zip.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"zip.d" -MT"zip.d" -o "zip.o" "../zip.c"
Finished building: ../zip.c
```

Linking is done by the linker (via the compiler using option `-o`):

```
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc  -o "unzipper"  ./zip.o   
./main.o: In function `zip':
/home/alk/workspace/unzipper/Debug/../zip.c:20: undefined reference to `zip_open'
/home/alk/workspace/unzipper/Debug/../zip.c:27: undefined reference to `zip_get_num_files'
/home/alk/workspace/unzipper/Debug/../zip.c:33: undefined reference to `zip_fopen_index'
/home/alk/workspace/unzipper/Debug/../zip.c:35: undefined reference to `zip_fread'
/home/alk/workspace/unzipper/Debug/../zip.c:38: undefined reference to `zip_fclose'
/home/alk/workspace/unzipper/Debug/../zip.c:43: undefined reference to `zip_close'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Eclipse provides a framework helping you in managing all sources and their references as also spawing compiler and linker tasks and setting their options.

When the linker told you there where `undefined reference`s to the `zip_*`function during the build of your program, the cause for this was, you were missing to tell the linker (via the compiler, via Eclipse) where those `zip_*` functions could be found.

Those `zip_*` functions are located in a library, namely `libzip`.

So what you as the programmer need to tell the linker (via the compiler, via Eclipse) is to link those functions against what the compiler compiled from your sources.

As the result the linker is able to create a runnable program from your compiled sources together with all libraries needed. Certain libraries are know to Eclipse (and therfore to the linker) by default, for example the one containing the C standard functions, namely `libc`.

To get things going:

1 Remove the source files you pulled from the `libzip` librarie's sources from your project. Those sources had been compiled into the library `libzip`, which you will use in your project.

2 Tell the linker (via Eclipse) to use `libzip` for your project.

Do so by following the steps below:

open the project's properties

click 'C/C++ General'

click 'Path and Symbols', on the left select the 'Libraries' tab, there click 'Add' and enter `zip`

finally click 'OK'

3 Then try to build your program:

```
Building target: unzipper
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc  -o "unzipper"  ./zip.o   -lzip
Finished building target: unzipper
```

(Please note additional option `-lzip`!)

If the developement version of 'libzip' had been installed properly before, you should be fine.

---

PS: `unzipper` was the name I used for the Eclispe project to produce the examples.

PSS: I used Eclipse Juno SR1